# Get the Report ID from a Dashboard Component

Tags: visualforce, reporting, dashboard

I have a list of Dashboard Component IDs and need to get the Report IDs from them to create a new Visualforce page with those reports.  How would I get the Custom Report IDs knowing the dashboard component ID?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not 100% the answer you're looking for, but you can get this information through the metadata API.  e.g. /src/dashboards/CampaignDashboard/CampaignMetricsDashboard.dashboard has this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dashboard xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<backgroundEndColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundEndColor>
<backgroundFadeDirection>Diagonal</backgroundFadeDirection>
<backgroundStartColor>#FFFFFF</backgroundStartColor>
<dashboardType>SpecifiedUser</dashboardType>
<leftSection>
    <columnSize>Medium</columnSize>
    <components>
        <autoselectColumnsFromReport>true</autoselectColumnsFromReport>
        <componentType>Gauge</componentType>
        <gaugeMax>500.0</gaugeMax>
        <gaugeMin>0.0</gaugeMin>
        <header>Lead Generation</header>
        <indicatorBreakpoint1>100.0</indicatorBreakpoint1>
        <indicatorBreakpoint2>200.0</indicatorBreakpoint2>
        <indicatorHighColor>#54C254</indicatorHighColor>
        <indicatorLowColor>#C25454</indicatorLowColor>
        <indicatorMiddleColor>#C2C254</indicatorMiddleColor>
        <report>CampaignDashboards/Allcampaignleadsthismonth</report>
        <showPercentage>false</showPercentage>
        <showTotal>false</showTotal>
        <showValues>false</showValues>
        <title>All Campaign leads generated this month</title>
    </components>
    <components>
        <autoselectColumnsFromReport>true</autoselectColumnsFromReport>
        <chartAxisRange>Auto</chartAxisRange>
        <componentType>Pie</componentType>
        <displayUnits>Auto</displayUnits>
        <drillEnabled>false</drillEnabled>
        <drillToDetailEnabled>false</drillToDetailEnabled>
        <enableHover>false</enableHover>
        <expandOthers>false</expandOthers>
        <legendPosition>Bottom</legendPosition>
        <report>CampaignDashboards/Leadsbyleadsource</report>
        <showPercentage>false</showPercentage>
        <showValues>false</showValues>
        <sortBy>RowLabelAscending</sortBy>
        <title>Leads by lead source</title>
        <useReportChart>false</useReportChart>
    </components>
</rightSection>
<runningUser>raytest@raytest.com</runningUser>
<textColor>#000000</textColor>
<title>Campaign Metrics Dashboard</title>
<titleColor>#000000</titleColor>
<titleSize>12</titleSize>
</Dashboard>
```